# How to query Ethereum contract to get data from it?

Tags: contract-invocation, etherscan

How to query Ethereum contract to get data from it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eth_call` as follows:

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_call&to=0xbc1869a652f68260428b382fd06c96196d92d02d&data=0x8620410b&tag=latest

Pass the first 4 bytes (8 characters) of the Keccak hash of the method, with `0x` prepended, as the `data` parameter. You can use [a tool like this](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html) to get the hash. In your case, you want to hash the string `buyPrice()` (different story if the method takes arguments). The first 8 characters of this are `8620410b`, leading to the data parameter provided above.

The returned value is a hexadecimal. Use your preferred approach to convert back to decimal. [Here's an online one](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html). You can drop any leading zeroes if your language chokes on the string length. For example, at the time of posting, the returned value was `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002e1d9ae30ae00`. You can reduce this to `0x2e1d9ae30ae00`, which is `811275000000000` wei (0.000811275ETH).

Note that there's a rate limit of 5 requests per second. Exceed that and you might be blacklisted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API. The function you need to use is eth_call. However, you will need the bytecode of: `function buyPrice` which you can get with web3 1.0.

Another way is using also web3, like this:

First, the buyPrice is returned by a function called the same `buyPrice`:

`function buyPrice() public`

Second you need to create an instance to the contract, for that you need the ABI of the contract, which you can obtain by copy-pasting the code of the contract in
remix then you can do can use Infura to access ethereum (is free) like this:

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("use infura acces token here")); 
ABI = "here all the ABI string"
var pyramidContract = web3.eth.contract(ABI);
var pyramidInstance = contrato.at('0xBc1869a652F68260428b382fd06C96196D92d02D')
pyramidInstance.buyPrice(function(err,result){
    console.log(result) // this is the returned value
})
```

Hope this help.

Comment: What should be the HTTP provider for the contract which is on etherum not in local?

Answer (score 0):

A perhaps more current realtime way based on web3 1.0 is:

```javascript
web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "ws://localhost:7545"); // local eth node
const contract = require('/path/contract.json');
const contractId = "0xcontractId";
const MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(Contract.abi, contractId);

// Use any contract methods, or watch any events/logs
MyContract.methods.myMethod(function(error, result) { /* callback */});
MyContract.events.myEvent(function(error, result) { /* callback */ });
```

You can use the `MyContract` object to access any of your contract methods, which may also return contract data. Additionally you can subscribe to a broader scope of events (by contract, contract event etc.) as decsribe in [the web3 1.0 documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html?highlight=logs#events)

```javascript
var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
    address: '0x123456..',
    topics: ['0x12345...']
    }, function(error, result){
    if (!error)
        console.log(result);
});
```